# overload member selection operator

Tags: c++, operator-overloading

is there any way to overload the "dot"-operator "."

We would like to use our old code base while rewriting the ORM layer. So we had the idea to wrap the objects and add some new semantic to the member selection operator "."

We found a several sites discussing that, including here on SO, all say in theory it would be fine but current C++ standard does not allow it.

Maybe there is already a compiler which does it?

**EDIT**

thanks for your quick answers; We see it might be hard if not impossible to find such a compiler. Any further hints are appreciated. All your posted resources we already had read...

Briefly what we want to achieve: The wrapper does not have any own members, it just should provide the former real object in another way. It would be very convenient to implement our new layer for reasons of backward compatibility - we could avoid to modify the legacy client code in about >4000 occurrences.

If you have any other idea how to proceed in another way, please tell. Will this limit be still there in C++11 ?

**EDIT 2**

Not sure yet, I am going to report what we do.

Comment: I saw that page, but seem not to find info about my qustion. Could you elaborate please

Comment: I guess you're right. I'm not sure what the exact reason it isn't overloadable is, but any compiler allowing it would then be non-standard-compliant.

Comment: @groovehunter I think it is a bad idea as it will probably make your code unreadable.

Comment: see [Stroustrup's FAQ](http://www.stroustrup.com/bs_faq2.html#overload-dot)

Comment: @DyP, I forgot I ever read that, thanks.

Comment: You could turn every `a.b` into an `(&a)->b` (or even plain `a->b`) and overload `->`. But this is even 'hackier' than your original intention. (Note: beware of `&` overloads..)

Comment: @groovehunter: `.` cannot be overloaded even in C++11. I guess it'll never be overloadable.

Comment: yes unfortunately that would not help either. If we would search+replace in client code we could change it right to the new access way...

Comment: It might be possible to use macros: if you have `#define x legacy_x()`, then `new_object.x = 9` will be magically replaced by `new_object.legacy_x() = 9`, which can be handled by overloading `operator=`

Comment: thanks anatolyg, also a suggestion my coworker already considered. But too dangerous he argued.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't overload the dot operator, and there is no c++ compiler that supports this property. Check this link from wikipedia which explains operator overloading in C++ in more detail. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C%2B%2B_operators